# How to filter a list using LINQ when the list has same properties?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a List of objects, like

```
class Hotel
{
     public int ID {get; set;}
     public string description {get; set;}
}
```

I have a `List<Hotel>` that has several items. What is LINQ for filtering the list when the `description` property of items are the same? So gives me a list of all the Hotels whose description is same.

Comment: `hotels.GroupBy(x=>x.description).Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1).SelectMany(x=>x);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

group by the description and filter to retain the groups where there is more than 1 item:

```
var resultSet = source.GroupBy(x => x.description)
                      .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

`resultSet` is of type `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Hotel>>` where each `IGrouping<string, Hotel>` represents a collection of `Hotel` objects that have the same description.

If for whatever reason you wish to merge the collection of `Hotel` objects in each `IGrouping` then you can use `SelectMany` to collapse the nested sequences.

```
var resultSet = source.GroupBy(x => x.description)
                      .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                      .SelectMany(x => x);
```